# Rails: call same method in after_commit for create, update, delete but do separate things based on certain flags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to create and delete the user on a 3rd party service based on the below scenarios

1. create user on 3rd party

   - when user is created in the application
   - marked as `active` from `inactive` (i have a column on my User model called `is_active`)
2. delete user on 3rd party

   - when user is deleted from the application
   - marked as `inactive`

looks like I can make use of the `after_commit` callback, but how do I identify in the `after_commit` that action is `create`, `update` or `delete`

Any help on this will be helpful.

Comment: You can specify that the callback should only be fired by a certain action with the `:on` option: `after_commit :do_foo, on: :create`, `after_commit :do_bar, on: :update`, `after_commit :do_foo_bar, on: [:create, :update]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use a callbacks for this -- you are going to regret it.
The main problem with callbacks are:

- No context -- you don't actually have any idea what's going on in the app.
- Its hard to control when the callback actually fires -- and more importantly when you don't want it to fire (like for example when loading fixtures).
- It puts too much responsibility on the model.
- You can't test the callback logic in isolation from creating/updating/destroying the record.

I really can't understate this when you seem to be dealing with a third party API as well. Using an implicit mechanism like callbacks when you're touching the application boundary is a really bad idea. The whole idea of piping everything through a single method is also not sound.

Instead you can use patterns such as [service objects](https://blog.appsignal.com/2020/06/17/using-service-objects-in-ruby-on-rails.html) to handle the "transformations" of the model.

```
class UserCreationService
  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end

  def perform
    # do something with @user
  end
end


class UserInactivationService
  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end

  def perform
    # do something with @user
  end
end
```

These do a single job and are easy to test and will only fire when you explicitly want them to. ActiveJob is actually an example of this pattern.

Comment: thanks @max for your reply. So i need to call the services explicitly, for example, when a user is created, in `RegistrationController` i need to call the service that creates the user on the 3rd party

Comment: Yes, thats the whole point.